# bind one handler to many events

Tags: jquery, events

How can I bind one handler to many events and make sure that the handler is called only once even if more than one events were fired?

```
$(".element").bind("click select" ,handl);
function handl (e) 
{ 
     //my code
}
```

The problem with this code is that the handl is called twice for each event. If you think that the handler should only be called once if both events are fired than please tell me so because I think that the handler in this code should be called twice.

Comment: FYI as of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: You already posted the solution (with the exception that one have to declare a function BEFORE using it) – so what is the problem? To execute only once you could use some switch – a variable that stores the number of executions…

Comment: Remove the listener from all event listener lists at the end of the handler.

Comment: the problem is that the handl is called twice for each event

Comment: @11684 now how do I do that?

Comment: @feeela you can declare the function later, though it might not be best practise, it would still work. (ref: hosting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly.. but I am assuming that you are trying to prevent multiple events calling the handler function multiple times from one user action.

```
var isExecuting = false;
$(".element").bind("click focus" ,function () {    
    if (isExecuting) return false;
    isExecuting = true;
    handl.call(this); //maintain the context
    isExecuting = false;
});
function handl (e) 
{ 
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Yes you understood correctly. I just had to make one small change and move `isExecuting = false;` to inside the handler. I'm not sure if that was specific to my code or not.

Answer (score 1):

use a closure to wrap your event function like this

```
$("#a").bind("click focus", function () {
    var fired = false;
    return function() {
        if (!fired) {
           alert("click occured");
           fired = true;
        }  
    } 
}());
```

[jsfiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/wguAk/2/)